# Tag merge + synonym request: [xbox-gamertag] → [xbox-live]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge-request

As discussed in [this year's burnination thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7936/52800). Can we merge [xbox-gamertag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-gamertag) with [xbox-live](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live) and then possibly make [xbox-gamertag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-gamertag) a synonym of [xbox-live](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live)?